# Hide asp.net GridView row with condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my grid

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gridProduct"  runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
    ShowFooter="true" 
    onrowcancelingedit="gridProduct_RowCancelingEdit" 
    onrowdeleting="gridProduct_RowDeleting" onrowediting="gridProduct_RowEditing" 
    onrowupdating="gridProduct_RowUpdating" 
    onrowcommand="gridProduct_RowCommand"
    onrowdatabound="gridProduct_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="buttonUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" ToolTip="Update" Text="Update" />
                <asp:Button ID="buttonCancel" CommandName="Cancel" runat="server" ToolTip="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="buttonEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" ToolTip="Edit"/>
                <asp:Button ID="buttonDelete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" ToolTip="Delete"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="buttonAdd" runat="server" Text="Ajouter" CommandName="AddNew" ToolTip="Add new User" ValidationGroup="validaiton" />
            </FooterTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#Piece">
            <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="labelEditPiece" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Piece") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="labelItemPiece" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Piece") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownListPartsFooter" runat="server" DataTextField="Nom" DataValueField="ID_AchatTemplate">
            </asp:DropDownList>   

             ControlToValidate="txtBoxPiece" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validaiton"/>--%>
            </FooterTemplate> 

             </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Series">
            <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="labelEditSeries" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Series") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="labelItemSeries" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Series") %>'/>

            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxSeries" runat="server"/>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="fieldValidSeries" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBoxSeries" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validaiton"/>
            </FooterTemplate> 

              .... </asp:TemplateField> 

           </Columns>
```

This is my page load

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        PsaDataSet psaList = new PsaDataSet();
        ViewState.Remove("psaList");
        ViewState.Add("psaList", psaList);
        ViewState.Add("psaUid", Guid.NewGuid());

        if (psaList.PsaLink.DefaultView.Count == 0)
             {

                // Patch for view  footer row when no data
                PsaDataSet.PsaLinkDataTable tmpList = new           PsaDataSet.PsaLinkDataTable();

                PsaDataSet.PsaLinkRow tmpItem = tmpList.NewPsaLinkRow();
                tmpItem.PsaUid = (Guid)ViewState["psaUid"];
                tmpItem.PsaProductUid = Guid.Empty;
                tmpItem.ProductId = 1;
                tmpItem.Series = "test";
                tmpItem.Rev = "test";
                tmpItem.Firmware = "test";
                tmpList.AddPsaLinkRow(tmpItem);
                tmpList.AcceptChanges();
                ViewState.Add("series", tmpItem.Series);


                gridProduct.DataSource = tmpList;
                gridProduct.DataBind();


            }

    }
    else
    {
        //BindGrid((PsaDataSet)ViewState["psaList"], false);

    }
}

private void BindGrid(PsaDataSet psaList, bool mustDataBind)
{

    gridProduct.DataSource = psaList.PsaLink;


    //if (mustDataBind)
    //{
        gridProduct.DataBind();
    //}
}
```

This my onrowdatabound="gridProduct_RowDataBound"> method

```
     protected void gridProduct_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "display:none";

            }
        }
 }
```

I want to add a condition (Based whit a test value inserted in page load)  in the if(protected void gridProduct_RowDataBound method) for hiding just one time on page load??

Thank Frank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive you can get the `DataBoundItem` from the row which is a type of "`PsaDataSet.PsaLinkRow`" and use that you get the ProductId, Series, etc. and do the condition that you require. Also, you have and if condition inside an if condition with the same condition for both. You only need one.